# file explorer in android

Tags: java, android

I made a program for simple database with the database name "employee.db" but i'm not finding the file explorer where i can see that if database is created or not. while running the code i'm getting this :-
[2011-09-09 14:52:19 - DatabaseExample] Failed to install DatabaseExample.apk on device 'emulator-5554': null
[2011-09-09 14:52:19 - DatabaseExample] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException
[2011-09-09 14:52:19 - DatabaseExample] Launch canceled!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse for development then download the Android development plugins and use the File Explorer in the DDMS perspective.

Alternativeley you could also use the `adb -shell` command from the Android SDK platform-tools to browse the file system.